# Hiding dates earlier than today on lightning-input field

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-inputfield

Is there way to grey out the dates which are less than today using a simple `<lightning-input type="date" name="input1" label="Enter a date" ></lightning-input>`

example:

[image]

I looked at `disabled` option but I am not sure how to use it to disable previous dates.

```
  <lightning-input type="date" name="input7" label="Disabled date field" disabled value="2020-09-07" ></lightning-input>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the min attrubute and pass it today's date dynamically `min="2020-09-29"`. Disabled attrubute will disable the entire input.

Comment: just tried, is there way for user to not select the previous date. I am able to select when using min

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_max_min):-

```
<input class="slds-input" type="date" id="datemin" name="datemin" min="2010-01-02">
```

or

```
<input class="slds-input" type="date" id="datemax" name="datemax" max="1979-12-31">
```

Html input field of type date restrict user from selecting date beyond max or min date.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<lightning-input type="date" onchange={handleCollectionDate} class="selector" min={mindate} disabled={disabled} >
</lightning-input>

@track mindate;
@track selector;
@track disabled;
    dispSelectedDate;
       connectedCallback() {
            let today = new Date() ;
            let dd = today.getDate() + 2;
            let mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
            let y = today.getFullYear();
            this.mindate = y + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
            console.log("mindate",this.mindate);    
            this.selector = 'cursor';
            this.dispSelectedDate = '';
            this.template.querySelectorAll('.selector').forEach(each => {
                each.value = '';
                });
          // if( this.getDay()==6|| this.getDay()==0){
           //     console.log('weekend', this.getDay());
           //    disabled=true;
           // }
        }
```